# Pass file path from file in listbox to dataconext C#

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, datacontext

I am populating a listbox with a file. This can be done by two methods, the open file dialog command initiated by a button press and a drag/drop action into the listbox. I want to pass on the file path (for the file in the listbox) to other areas of my code, for example the `DataContext` that reads the file in the listbox. Basically I want the file path to automatically update when the listbox is populated. I am new to C# so sorry if I haven't explained myself properly or provided enough information. The code for populating my listbox (named FilePathBox) and the 'Run' button is as follows:

```
private void BrowseButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var openFileDialog = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
    //openFileDialog.Multiselect = true;
    openFileDialog.Filter = "Csv files(*.Csv)|*.Csv|All files(*.*)|*.*";
    openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

    if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog())
    {
        FilePathBox.Items.Clear();

        foreach (string filename in openFileDialog.FileNames)
        {
            ListBoxItem selectedFile = new ListBoxItem();

            selectedFile.Content = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename);
            selectedFile.ToolTip = filename;                    
            FilePathBox.Items.Add(selectedFile);
        }
    }          
}


private void FilesDropped(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
     {
        FilePathBox.Items.Clear();

        string[] droppedFilePaths = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, true) as string[];

        foreach (string droppedFilePath in droppedFilePaths)
        {
            ListBoxItem fileItem = new ListBoxItem();

            fileItem.Content = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(droppedFilePath);
            fileItem.ToolTip = droppedFilePath;
            FilePathBox.Items.Add(fileItem);
        }
    }  
}

private void RunButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataContext = OldNewService.ReadFile(@"C:\Users\Documents\Lookup Table.csv");
}
```

Comment: Switch to real MVVM, and this code will work a lot better *and* make more sense. Why you are even bothering with the data context without MVVM is beyond me.

Comment: are you populating the listbox with one file path or multiple files, it seems that you are populating multiple files, so you may need a selectedIndexChanged listener to provide the selection from the listbox, if that is what you need, I can provide you with an example

Comment: Hi BradleyDotNET, do you have any link to somewhere I could learn more about your suggestion. I am rather new to this and have been self-teaching myself without much guidance. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I added a comment, but I think what you need a way to get the selected file path when the RunButton is clicked, so just add this to your RunButton_Click method,

```
private void RunButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  string selection = (string)FilePathBox.SelectedItem;
  DataContext = OldNewService.ReadFile(selection);
}
```